# How to hide a field on a form with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, drupal

So I am working on hiding a input field, which I later plan to have dynamically loaded with the other form fields. I have created a small module to assist in this process.

```
/**
*  Implements hook_form_alter().
*/

function editorhide_form_alter(&$form,$form_id){
//form id = artist_node_form
//title id = edit-title label: edit-title

global $user;

if($form_id == 'artist_node_form'){

   if(in_array('editor', $user->roles)){
        drupal_add_js("$(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#edit-title').css('display','none;');});"
        );

    }
}

}
```

however when looking at the element in question that needs to be hidden it doesn't go any where.  My basic path I'm taking is:: Logged in as "editor"(admin privilages) -> Content -> Artist -> "Edit". At this point a light box (?) pops up with the fields to fill in to allow a person to person to add to the content. What am I missing..?

EDIT: Fixed the missing $(document) portion, still not hiding the field however.

Img:: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWDZw.jpg

Comment: You could also hide it with CSS onload.

Comment: document object has no ready handler. Ready pseudo event is a jquery one, so use it on jquery object: `$(document)`

Comment: @A.Wolff So it should be like my edit I take it.

Comment: I take it you've included jQuery on the page? Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @nnnnnn Drupal should be auto including jQuery for me, the console log has no errors on it. Correction: I went and downloaded a jQuery plugin module so it should be on now, still the same issue however.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have this line...

```
$('#edit-title').css('display','none;');
```

Try making use of jQuery "hide" ability...

```
$('#edit-title').hide();
```

also, the CSS way isn't working because you have a semi-colon after 'none'. Doesn't need to be there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should bind this event dynamically, in Jquery 1.x you can test it

```
if(in_array('editor', $user->roles)){
        drupal_add_js("$(document).live("ready",function(){
                        $('#edit-title').css('display','none;');});"
        );

    }
```

or in jquery 2.x,

```
if(in_array('editor', $user->roles)){
        drupal_add_js("$(document)bind('ready', function(){
                        $('#edit-title').css('display','none;');});"
        );

    }
```